# Codeception logs are not writable

Tags: codeception

I am on CentOS 6.5.  I ran this command

```
codecept run tests/api/certification.php
```

The result was this error:

```
  [Codeception\Exception\Configuration] 
Path for logs is not writable. Please, set appropriate access mode for log path.
```

The directory structure of the Test directory is:

```
➜  ocean git:(OCEAN-3431) ✗ pwd
/home/davidNovo/projects/ocean
➜  ocean git:(OCEAN-3431) ✗ cd tests 
➜  tests git:(OCEAN-3431) ✗ ls -l
total 76
drwxrwxr-x. 3 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct  6 17:35 acceptance
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo  802 Oct  6 17:35 acceptance.suite.yml
drwxrwxr-x. 2 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct 16 15:37 api
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo  674 Oct 16 15:37 api.suite.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo  632 Oct 15 12:03 _bootstrap.php
drwxrwxrwx  2 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct 19 16:57 _data
drwxrwxr-x. 2 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct  6 17:35 functional
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo  304 Oct  6 17:35 functional.suite.yml    
drwxrwxr-x. 2 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct 16 15:37 _helpers
drwxrwxrwx  2 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct 19 16:39 _log
drwxrwxr-x. 9 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct  6 17:35 phpunit
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo 2038 Oct  6 17:35 phpunit.xml.dist
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo 6192 Oct  6 17:35 README.md
drwxrwxr-x. 2 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct 15 12:03 _support
drwxrwxr-x. 5 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct 15 12:03 unit
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo  851 Oct  6 17:35 unit.suite.yml
drwxrwxr-x. 2 davidNovo davidNovo 4096 Oct  6 17:35 upi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 davidNovo davidNovo  668 Oct  6 17:35 upi.suite.yml
```

Comment: What version of Codeception is that? _log directory was renamed to _output many versions ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I am using codeception version 1.8.7

Second, there are two codeceptionh.yml files.  The one in the root of the project looks like this:

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_logs
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_helpers
```

So, I misspelled the directory I needed.